# What is causing these strange colors in the console when using WriteConsoleOutputAttribute?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I am currently trying to format a console window with characters in certain positions with color-coding to make things fun. All was fine and simple until I tried to perform a simple coloring operation to a line of text on row 4, which resulted in many odd background colors and foreground colors being mixed. What could be the cause of this?

I have created a simple reproducible example:

[image: WriteConsoleOutputAttribute bug]

```
#define UNICODE

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hStdErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    
    SMALL_RECT consoleCoords{0, 0, 79, 19};
    COORD sbSize{80, 20};
    
    if(!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdOut, TRUE, &consoleCoords)) /* HANDLE hConsoleOutput, BOOL bAbsolute, const SMALL_RECT* lpConsoleWindow */
    {
        wcout << L"SetConsoleWindowInfo failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << L'\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hStdOut, sbSize)) /* HANDLE hConsoleOutput, COORD dwSize */
    {
        wcout << L"SetConsoleScreenBufferSize failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << L'\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    DWORD cCharsWritten{};
    DWORD attrsWritten{};
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bufferInfo{};
    DWORD dwConsoleSz{};
    system("pause");
    
    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &bufferInfo))
    {
        wcout << L"GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    dwConsoleSz = bufferInfo.dwSize.X * bufferInfo.dwSize.Y; /* X (character cells) * Y (character cells) */
    COORD cursorHome{0, 0};
    /* Now we fill the entire screen with blanks. */
    if(!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
            hStdOut,
            L' ',
            dwConsoleSz,
            cursorHome,
            &cCharsWritten
        )
    )
    {
        wcout << L"FillConsoleOutputCharacter failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, cursorHome))
        /*Research is needed regarding this function as it does not seem to move the cursor. */
    {
        wcout << L"SetConsoleCursorPosition failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << '\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    
    wchar_t topmiddlebottomRow[] = L"================";
    wchar_t separatorString[] = L"================================================================================";
    
    LPCWSTR writeRow = topmiddlebottomRow;
    LPCWSTR writeSeparator = separatorString;
    
    WORD S_attr = FOREGROUND_GREEN;
    
    if(!WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hStdOut, writeRow, 16, COORD{64, 0}, &cCharsWritten))
    {
        wcout << L"WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << L'\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hStdOut, writeRow, 16, COORD{64, 1}, &cCharsWritten))
    {
        wcout << L"WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << L'\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hStdOut, writeRow, 16, COORD{64, 2}, &cCharsWritten))
    {
        wcout << L"WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << L'\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hStdOut, writeSeparator, 80, COORD{0, 4}, &cCharsWritten))
    {
        wcout << L"WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << L'\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    if(!WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut, &S_attr, 80, COORD{0, 4}, &attrsWritten))
    {
        wcout << L"WriteConsoleOutputAttribute failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError() << L'\n';
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    
    while(1)
    {
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The #pragma comment preprocessor line may be unnecessary - I am still learning.

EDIT: I was able to solve the issue here by applying the necessary character attributes successively in a loop.

Comment: Those colors look familiar, havent seen them since late 90's or so ;)
They where part of attributes back then I guess you're outputing some control bits by accident because you are using wchar_t and I suspect the buffer expects plain ascii/

Comment: Could this be? I suppose there must be a way to accommodate for wchar_t.

Comment: Every single call to `GetLastError` is happening too late. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) explains how this API call needs to be used.

Comment: WriteConsoleOutputAttribute() expects an array of attributes and you're only giving it one. Thus it's reading garbage values for the rest which is why it's random after the first character.

Comment: This seemed to resolve the issue. Rather than trying to create an array of eighty "FOREGROUND_GREEN" WORD objects I used a for loop - interesting solution.